# Make a String in java Global

Tags: java, android, string, public-method

I am an Android developer and I have made a string for generating a random 6-digit OTP which is there in the `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`, the first thing in a java program.:

```
String otp = new DecimalFormat("000000").format(new Random().nextInt(999999));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your OTP is " + otp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have another `public void` in my java program in which I have to call the OTP String but, I don't know how to do that.

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: U can move the String outside of the method scope and add the ‘static’ keyword in front of it. (Though this is usually bad design)

Comment: provide some more source code of `onCreate()` and your other method that invoke `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your String variable either as a class(static) variable or instance variable in your class.

**Sample solution**

```
public class Main{
   String otp; //Define your variable here


   public void method1(){

      //Now you can access the variable otp and you can make changes

   }

  public void method2(){

     //Now you can access the variable otp and you can make changes


  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer really helped me.

Comment: @AnikethChavare glad to be of help please up vote the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define the string as a class data member, initialize it in the onCreate method and have everyone in the same class access that data member.
As in:

```
String mOTP;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mOTP = new DecimalFormat("000000").format(new Random().nextInt(999999));
... Rest of code
}
```

Or, you can create another class, named Consts or something of the sort, and create a static String there and access it from where ever in your project.

```
public static class Consts{
     public static String OTP_STRING;
}
```

and then in mainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Consts.OTP_STRING = new DecimalFormat("000000").format(new Random().nextInt(999999));
... Rest of code
}
```